# how to deploy flask app with jaydebeapi on pivotal cloud foundry

Tags: python, flask, jvm, cloud-foundry, jaydebeapi

So i tried to push flask app that manipulate db using jaydebeapi on pcf, but it cannot find the jvm,and i tried this one

[Add Java/JRE/JVM in Python Flask Cloud Foundry/IBM Cloud application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48356280/add-java-jre-jvm-in-python-flask-cloud-foundry-ibm-cloud-application)

using multipacks return "No container can run this application", and the .profile didn't make any difference either.

this is the result when i add .profile containing the jre path in my computer file in my project direction

[image: with .profile]

and this is when i used multi-buildpack, according to the link above

[image: with multi-buildpack]

Comment: Instead of taking pictures of text, please copy the actual text to your question (and format it with the code format)

Comment: I updated the SO question you linked to with a more modern answer. You might want to try that. Also, the second screenshot is failing cause you're adding in the Java buildpack. See my answer on the other post for why that won't work. As to the first failure, there's not enough logs to see. As @JamesZ said, copy actual logs, not a screenshot, and include all the output from after you run `cf push` to the point it fails. Include all that in your question. Thanks